# save passwords for my website using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, passwords

Rigth now i'm creating my own website and there need to be a log in function. I've made a sign up page that retrieves data from the input fields and now comes the problem. I don't know how to save the passwords and username etc. Is it possible to save this into a text file and every time i open the website it retrieves this data? So, yes how do i do this and if this can't is there another way?

Here you see the code it retrieves. These variables need to be safed in a text file and retrieved next time website will be opend

```
        var voornaam = document.getElementById("voorn").value;
        var achternaam = document.getElementById("achtern").value;
        var mail = document.getElementById("mail").value;
        var password = document.getElementById("pass").value;
        var gender = document.getElementById("iGender").value;
```

Solution:

Use a Database to save this information. Here a some Databases Mongo DB and Firebase

https://www.firebase.com/

Here's a course for Firebase http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/firebase

Comment: Um, why are you not using one of the countless password plugins for the browser that does this?

Comment: Why 2 down votes, please tell me why so i can do this beter for the next time i make a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to hashing the password, you probably want to be storing this information in a database. You will then have to add some logic to your application so that when a user logs in to your website, the values they enter into the log in form are checked against the values stored in the database when they signed up. In very general terms, that is probably the most standard architecture to get a log in functionality up and running.

Comment: Thanks, but how do i save this information in a database. Do i do this using a API or something.

Comment: This would depend on the database that you are using. The way you could structure it is to have a database running wherever your application is hosted. Then whenever the form is submitted, your application would be able to access the database and save the information. I would recommend you check out MongoDB if you are considering different database solutions.

Comment: You're welcome. Also, if you want to have a hands on introduction to creating a login functionality with MongoDB, check out the free M101 courses [here](https://university.mongodb.com/). The course project is a blog and in the first couple of weeks the course covers logging functionality. It might help.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write a service on your server that takes the form values, checks them against a database and then updates the HTML accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a cookie and read it when the page loads: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Create: `document.cookie = "voornaam="+voornaam`

Read: `$(function(){ voornaam = document.cookie.replace("voornaam=",""); })`

EDIT:

To save objects, you can use the JSON-library like so:

`document.cookie = JSON.stringify({foo:"bar"}); cookieObject = JSON.parse(document.cookie);`

But have in mind that the user can read and manipulate this cookie...

Comment: Where will this cookie be saved? Will it be saved on the server, or what? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Is it also possible to save a object in a cookie. Suck like `var james = { firstname: james, lastname: bond, email: james@hotmail.com};`

Comment: The cookie will be saved on the clients computer. (Srsly, you never heard of cookies as a web developer?^^). And yes, you can save objects, have a look at my edit.

Comment: I think i could use this cus only the user of the computer can acess it and it don't need to be a very secure password.